# Laravel Eloquent order Relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

When having a Eloquent relation, you get the relation like:

`$page->photos->toArray();`.

But I want the relation ordered. How?

`$page->photos->orderBy('order')->toArray();` does now work: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy()`

Comment: Can you improve your controller code in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the returned relation as a builder object from your relation method.

```
$page->photos()->orderBy('order')->get();
```

`$page->photos()` returns a relation type object and `$page->photos` is the dynamic property that loads the relationship and returns the result. In this case an `Eloquent\Collection`.

[Docs - Eloquent - Dynamic Properties](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#dynamic-properties)

You can also order this relationship while eager loading if needed.

[Eager Loading Constraints](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading) (there is an example that uses orderBy in the docs)

Answer (score 3):

By calling the method of the relation you get the **relation object** on which you can run further queries. Now you're using the dynamic property which get's you the **result** of the relation.

```
$page->photos()->orderBy('order')->get()->toArray();
```